# GtkTreeView Unset Cursor

Tags: c, gtk, gtktreeview

When a new `GtkTreeView` is exposed, one finds it in a state without any cursor displayed. Once focused, the cursor is there, even when the focus is lost. I am looking for a method to get rid of the cursor on demand.

The GTK+ reference claims, that the function `gtk_tree_view_set_cursor` does the job whenever the `GtkTreePath*` argument is invalid for the `GtkTreeView*`. The term "invalid" can be interpreted in many ways. I experimented with many possibilities with results ranging between segfault and no effect at all. Therefore I would like ask:

> Q1: Is it even possible to unset a cursor on a GtkTreeView?
>
> Q2: If so, would you please provide a simple example, preferably in plain C?

Answer (score 3):

For the record:

I've tried using `gtk_tree_view_set_cursor()` to no avail.

Anyway, you can unset the cursor of a `GtkTreeView` using `gtk_tree_view_get_selection()` and then calling `gtk_tree_selection_unselect_all()` on the resulting `GtkTreeSelection`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but I believe I can help.

First of all, the [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-cursor) says that:

> If path is invalid for model, the current cursor (if any) will be
>   unset and the function will return without failing.

So the term invalid would refer to an invalid path for the [GtkTreeModel](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTreeModel.html).

Anyway, it also says that "This function is often followed by gtk_widget_grab_focus (tree_view) in order to give keyboard focus to the widget". I don't know if you've tried it since you said "even when the focus is lost", but maybe giving the focus to another widget with [gtk_widget_grab_focus](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-grab-focus) will solve your problem.